# Can I design a table that will use some columns just in certain times?

Tags: database-design

I have a `User` with one or more saved `Documents`, but each `Document` has specific attributes in Brasil for example we have:

- RG(General Register) have the following attributes:

  1. A number
  2. Expedition Date
  3. Emission Org
- CPF(Like a Social Security Number) have the following attributes:

  1. A number
- CNPJ(Like a National Registry of Legal Entities) have the following attributes:

  1. A Name (of a company)
  2. A Number
- CNH(Driver's License) have the following attributes:

  1. A Name (Of a person)
  2. A Number
  3. Expedition Date
  4. Valid Date

Then I designed the following model:

[image]

`FK Document Type` will control what attributes of table will be null, for example if`FK Document Type` appoint to `CPF`  the `Valid Date` attribute will not be used.

That's the correclty way to design a system with more than one type of document? I think that is not good make one table to each document type.

Comment: I would recommend an Entity/Type/Attribute/Value (EAV) style table for this.  Enforcement of allowed nullable / valid values gets pushed up to your application layer, but it gives you the flexibility of not having to define a table for each type of document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing number of repeating DocType `names` you store the `ids` of the DocType descriptions from the reference table. This is a common practice called `normalization`.

The sparsed table with nullable attributes is good enough while the number of possible attributes isn't too big. Sometimes it's more efficient to store all the attributes in the aux table `docid -- attrname -- value` containing only not-null values and join them whenever you need.

```
SELECT ud.*, da.*
  FROM UserDocuments  AS ud
  JOIN DocsAttributes AS da ON da.doc_id = ud.id
 WHERE ud.ID = 12345      -- for certain document only
```

The only difference is that by join you'll get not the single row but the table like that:

```
            UserDocuments      |       DocsAttributes 
 ------+----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------
    id | FK_users | FK_DocType | doc_id | attrname |     value
 ------+----------+------------+--------+----------+-----------
 12345 |      456 |          7 |  12345 | RGNumber |       9876
 12345 |      456 |          7 |  12345 |  RGEDate | 2019-05-01
 12345 |      456 |          7 |  12345 |   RGEOrg |       7777
 12345 |      456 |          7 |  12345 |   CPFNum |      88888
```

This table can be easily parsed on the app side.

An advantage of that approach is that you can add as many attributes as you want. Attributes names can be separated into the reference table for the normalization reasons.

The main disadvantage is that all attributes should be converted into the same type (VARCHAR() for example) and some functionality can be lost - like datetime arithmetics and/or timezone conversions.

Having a number of tables for each type of document isn't a good design.

There is no universal recipe and you have to decide what approach is suitable for you. Sometimes single table with hardcoded list of attributes is preferrable. Sometimes an expandable table of EAVs (entity-attribute-value) fits better.

Comment: I Adjusted my design with your example and I finally understood :) Just one question, your example is a EAV design?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Yes EAV approach was shown. Sparsed table you have described in the question.